# Issues with case statement (organizing depts by number of courses)

Tags: mysql, case

Essentially I am trying to make a case statement that counts the number of courses in the **Computer Science** dept, **Biology** dept, and the total of all other courses in a row named **Others**.

It should look like this:

[image]

Here's what my query actually displays:

[image]

Please let me know if something doesn't make sense or you need more information. Thanks!

This is the table schema and data:

```
create table course (
    course_id varchar(8),
    title varchar(50), 
    dept_name varchar(20),
    credits numeric(2,0) check (credits > 0),
    primary key (course_id)
);

insert into course values ('BIO-101', 'Intro. to Biology', 'Biology', '4');
insert into course values ('BIO-301', 'Genetics', 'Biology', '4');
insert into course values ('BIO-399', 'Computational Biology', 'Biology', '3');
insert into course values ('CS-101', 'Intro. to Computer Science', 'Comp. Sci.', '4');
insert into course values ('CS-190', 'Game Design', 'Comp. Sci.', '4');
insert into course values ('CS-315', 'Robotics', 'Comp. Sci.', '3');
insert into course values ('CS-319', 'Image Processing', 'Comp. Sci.', '3');
insert into course values ('CS-347', 'Database System Concepts', 'Comp. Sci.', '3');
insert into course values ('EE-181', 'Intro. to Digital Systems', 'Elec. Eng.', '3');
insert into course values ('FIN-201', 'Investment Banking', 'Finance', '3');
insert into course values ('HIS-351', 'World History', 'History', '3');
insert into course values ('MU-199', 'Music Video Production', 'Music', '3');
insert into course values ('PHY-101', 'Physical Principles', 'Physics', '4');
```

And this is my current query:

```
select
    dept_name,
    case
        when dept_name = 'Comp. Sci.' then count(course_id)
        when dept_name = 'Biology' then count(course_id)
        else count(course_id)
    end as 'Courses'
from
    course
group by
    dept_name;
```

Comment: Please, can you include a set of data so we can try a query and test on it.

Comment: @Shidersz I added the insert statements and the course table above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach for this query would be create a `new_dept_name` column for join the requires departments names that will go into the label `Other`, then `group by` this new column, and finally use the standard `count()` over these groups:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN dept_name = "Biology" THEN "Biology"
        WHEN dept_name = "Comp. Sci." THEN "Comp. Sci."
        ELSE "Other"
    END AS new_dept_name,
    count(course_id) AS numCourses
FROM
    course
GROUP BY
    new_dept_name
```

You can check an online example here:

[DB FIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/93HA5f6QWecQ8s7hBiN7KG/1)

Comment: thank you. I can also see now I was trying to display the course count in the conditions when I should've been doing it after 'end'.

Comment: You are welcome, please take in consideration to upvote and mark as correct if you like: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers